# Show latest posts all from unique tags (Rails 3.0, Acts_As_Taggable_On)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller, ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-taggable-on

tags_controller.rb:

```
def index
  @title = "tags"
  @posts = Post.tag_counts.collect do |tag|
    Post.tagged_with(tag).first(:order => "updated_at DESC")
  end
  @posts.uniq!
end
```

tags/index.html.rb:

```
<%= render 'latest' %>
```

_latest.html.erb:

```
<%- for post in @posts -%>
  <%- post.tags.each do |t| -%>
    <%= link_to t.name, tag_path(t) %>
  <%- end -%>
<%- end -%>
```

My goal is to show only the latest 10 posts, each with a unique tag. The current code above shows unique tags, but more than 10. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I just used will_paginate to solve this.